# Can I remote manage a Hyper-V Server that's running on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, hyper-v

I have a Hyper-V Server running on a Windows 8 machine (machine A). I have another Windows 8 laptop (machine B) that has Hyper-V Management GUI installed . Now when I connect Hyper-V Server from machine B to machine A, it gives me the following error:

> **Hyper-V Manager**
>
> An error occurred while attempting to connect to server "KEFEI-HOME". Check that the Virtual Machine Management service is running and that you are authorized to connect to the server.
>
> You do not have the required permission to complete this task. Contact the administrator of the authorization policy for the computer 'KEFEI-HOME'.

I'm wondering if it's possible to allow remote Hyper-V management for a Hyper-V Server running on a Windows 8 machine.

Answer (score 3):

On the machine you want to manage, run `dcomcnfg`.

Go to `Component Services`, then `Computers` and right-click `My Computer` and choose `Properties`.

Go to the `COM Security` tab, and under `Access Permissions`, click `Edit Limits`.

Click `ANONYMOUS LOGON` and check the `Remote Access` box under `Allow`.

Click OK, then OK again.

Comment: Is there security concern out of it? Under what assumption is it considered safe?

Comment: This is how Server 2012 is setup out of the box. How safe this is will depend on other factors such as your Endpoint security and your own network. You still have to authenticate with the Hyper-V server.