# Connect to Hyper V running in Windows 8 from a different Windows 8 machine in a homegroup

Tags: windows-8, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v, workgroup

I have 2 computers with Windows 8.1 Pro in a Homegroup.  Computer A has Hyper-V installed with several VM's.  Computer B just has the management tools, including Hyper-V Manager.  I am trying to connect to computer A from Computer B in Hyper-V Manager.  When I try I receive an error:

"An error occured while attempting to connect to server "Computer A". Check that the Virtual Machine Management service is running and that you are authorized to connect to the server.

You do not have the required permission to complete this task.  Contact the administrator of the authorization policy for the computer "Computer A"."

I have tried several suggestions I have found online to resolve this.  I have created an account on both machines with the same user name and password, both with admin rights, and both in the Hyper-V Administrators group.  I have tried shift right-clicking Hyper-V Manager and running it as the account on Computer A.  I receive the same error.

I have also tried the dcomcnfg thing from here:
[Can I remote manage a Hyper-V Server that's running on Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/588687/can-i-remote-manage-a-hyper-v-server-thats-running-on-windows-8#new-answer?newreg=29324d8c7f2849d0a343653be2691f46)

I still receive the same error, and I have rebooted both machines just to make sure all the changes have taken place.  I really don't know what else to do.  Almost every result I find when I search is for Hyper V server in a domain environment.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same configuration and I had the same problem.

1. On Computer B: add Computer A to hosts
2. Goto: [Hyper-V Remote Management Configuration Utility (HVRemote)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Hyper-V-Remote-Management-26d127c6),
   download hvremote.wsf and follow "10-second guide".

If something is still wrong just verify your configuration with this neat script (big thanks to its author!) and it will tell you, what you need to fix.